# Shell command in Java with Runtime.getRuntime().exec();

Tags: java, shell

Is this a simple and good way to execute a Shell command  via Java?

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec( some command );`

Or is this bad practice?

Comment: It makes your code platform dependent so you should avoid executing shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It depends.**

The original purpose and basic functionality of a Unix shell is to let you run programs, optionally passing them arguments. For example the command `ls` runs the `ls` program, and the command `grep foo bar` runs the `grep` program with the arguments `foo` and `bar`. **If your command only runs a (fixed) program with fixed if any arguments, `Runtime.exec` can do it.** There are two subcases:

- the overloads taking a `String` parse the line into 'words' (program name and arguments) using any whitespace; this is essentially the same as the default parsing (with no quoting) done by standard shells.
- if you need any different parsing, for example if your command would use any quoting in shell, you must do that parsing yourself and pass the *results* to one of the overloads taking a `String[]`.

But note that when you run a program from an *interactive* shell -- one using a terminal or equivalent (sometimes called a console) for input and output -- the program's input and output default to that terminal. The I/O for a program run by `Runtime.exec` is always pipes from and to the Java process, and some programs behave differently when their input and/or output is/are pipe(s) -- or file(s) -- instead of a terminal. Plus you must write code to send (write) any desired input and receive (read) any output. Of course, shells can be and sometimes are run without a terminal too.

However, shells can be and routinely are used to do much much more than the basics:

- shell can execute commands with contents different from the input by variable (formally parameter) substitution (possibly with modification/editing), command substitution, process substitution, special notations like squiggle and bang, and filename expansion aka 'globbing' (so called because in the early versions of Unix it was done by a separate program named `glob`). `Runtime.exec` doesn't do these, although you can write Java code to produce the same resulting command execution by very different means.
- shell executes some commands directly in the shell rather than by running a program, because these commands affect the shell process itself,
  like `cd umask ulimit exec source/. eval exit alias/unalias`, or variables in the shell like `set shift unset export local readonly declare typeset let read readarray/mapfile`,
  or child process like `jobs fg bg`, or special parsing like `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` (in some shells). These are called 'builtin' and `Runtime.exec` can't do them,
  with two partial exceptions: it can run a program with a different working directory and/or env var settings, equivalent to having previously executed `cd` or `export` or equivalent.
  Shell also often has builtins that duplicate, or modify, a 'normal' program; these commonly include `test/[ echo printf kill time`. `Runtime.exec` can only do the program version, not the builtin version.
- shell has control structures (compound commands) like `if/then/else/elif/fi` and `while/for/do/done` and `trap && || ( ) { }`. `Runtime.exec` can't do these, although in some cases you could use Java logic to produce the same results.
  shell can also have user-defined functions and aliases that can be used as commands; `Runtime.exec` does not.
- shell can redirect the I/O of programs it runs, including forming pipes. `Runtime.exec` can't do these, but see below.

Since 1.5, Java also has `ProcessBuilder`, which provides the same functionality and more, in a more flexible and arguably clearer API, and thus is generally recommended instead. `ProcessBuilder` does support redirecting I/O for the program it runs, including using the terminal/console *if* the JVM was run on/from one (which is not always the case), and since 9 it can build a pipeline. It does not have the word-splitting functionality of `Runtime.exec(String)` but you can easily get the same result with `string.split("[ \t]+")` or in most cases just `" +"`.

Note shell is itself a program, so you can use either `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder` to run a shell and pass *it* a command, either as an argument using option `-c` (on standard shells at least) or as input, and unsurprisingly this shell command can do anything a shell command can do.
But this can be a portability issue because different systems may have different shells, although any system claiming Unix certification or POSIX conformance must have a shell *named* `sh` that meets certain minimum requirements.
The actual shell used on different systems might be any of `bash dash ksh ash` or even more. OTOH this is true for other programs as well; some programs that typically differ significantly on different systems are `awk sed grep` and anything to do with administration like `netstat`.

A few of the existing Qs that show shell commands that don't work in `Runtime.exec` at least as-is:
[a command for sherlock.py is interpreted differently from linux command line and java process api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802065/a-command-for-sherlock-py-is-interpreted-differently-from-linux-command-line-and)
[Execute shell script multiple commands in one line using Process Builder in Java (Unix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002993/execute-shell-script-multiple-commands-in-one-line-using-process-builder-in-java)
[Check in Java if a certain application is in focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944386/check-in-java-if-a-certain-application-is-in-focus)
[Problem in executing command on AIX through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57737289/problem-in-executing-command-on-aix-through-java)
[ProcessBuilder doesn't recognise embedded command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56774440/processbuilder-doesnt-recognise-embedded-command)
[File not Found when executing a python scipt from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54206219/file-not-found-when-executing-a-python-scipt-from-java)
[Java system command to load sqlite3 db from file fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020511/java-system-command-to-load-sqlite3-db-from-file-fails)
[Curl To Download Image In JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994991/curl-to-download-image-in-java)
[Keytool command does not work when invoked with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988220/keytool-command-does-not-work-when-invoked-with-java)
[use javap from within a java program on all the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311604/use-javap-from-within-a-java-program-on-all-the-files)
[Using SSMTP and ProcessBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49223605/using-ssmtp-and-processbuilder)
[Process Builder Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801500/process-builder-arguments)
[Whitespace in bash path with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425729/whitespace-in-bash-path-with-java)
[java.lang.Runtime exception "Cannot run program"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500899/java-lang-runtime-exception-cannot-run-program-cat)
[Why does Runtime.exec(String) work for some but not all commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776546/why-does-runtime-execstring-work-for-some-but-not-all-commands)
[How to save Top command output in a text or csv file in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842190/how-to-save-top-command-output-in-a-text-or-csv-file-in-java)
[Execute bash-command in Java won't give a return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991406/execute-bash-command-in-java-wont-give-a-return)
[Using Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec I get error with some commands, success with others -- how can this be determined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902563/using-javas-runtime-getruntime-exec-i-get-error-with-some-commands-success-w)
[Java and exec command - pipe multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779095/java-and-exec-command-pipe-multiple-commands)
[Java exec() does not return expected result of pipes' connected commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088917/java-exec-does-not-return-expected-result-of-pipes-connected-commands)
[How to make pipes work with Runtime.exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928225/how-to-make-pipes-work-with-runtime-exec)
[How to use Pipe Symbol through exec in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226538/how-to-use-pipe-symbol-through-exec-in-java)
[In Runtime.getRuntime().exec() getting error: /bin/bash: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198482/in-runtime-getruntime-exec-getting-error-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directo)
[Java exec linux command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097095/java-exec-linux-command)
[How to use pipes in a java Runtime.exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31998982/how-to-use-pipes-in-a-java-runtime-exec)
[Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec and the vertical bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642415/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-and-the-vertical-bar)
[Whenever I execute terminal command from code it gives "cannot run program" error=2 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398871/whenever-i-execute-terminal-command-from-code-it-gives-cannot-run-program-erro)
[Command line proccess read linux in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51098328/command-line-proccess-read-linux-in-java)
[Java Command line system call does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577645/java-command-line-system-call-does-not-work-properly)